# Warning: DateTime::setTimestamp() expects parameter 1 to be long

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, timestamp

I am new here, so sorry if I am posing this question incorrectly... but I am getting this error:

Warning: DateTime::setTimestamp() expects parameter 1 to be long

For this code:

```
if(!function_exists('sort_posts_by_time')) {
function sort_posts_by_time($a, $b) {

    // set the times from the meta values
    $time_a = new DateTime();
    $time_a->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($a->ID, '_jfc_start_date', true));
    if($start_time_a = get_post_meta($a->ID, '_jfc_start_time', true)) {
        $time_a->modify($start_time_a);
    }

    $time_b = new DateTime();
    $time_b->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($b->ID, '_jfc_start_date', true));
    if($start_time_b = get_post_meta($b->ID, '_jfc_start_time', true)) {
        $time_b->modify($start_time_b);
    }

    if($time_a == $time_b) {

        $time_a->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($a->ID, '_jfc_end_time', true));

        $time_b->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($b->ID, '_jfc_end_time', true));

    }

    return ($time_a->getTimestamp() > $time_b->getTimestamp()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

}

The error specifically occurs within the code, above, here:

```
$time_a->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($a->ID, '_jfc_end_time', true));

$time_b->setTimestamp(get_post_meta($b->ID, '_jfc_end_time', true));
```

I am hoping someone can help me out, I have looked all over google search and haven't found anything helpful, thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code of the function *get_post_meta*. It seems not to (always) return a numeric value.

Comment: What's an example of the `get_post_meta($a->ID, '_jfc_end_time', true)` part? The function setTimestamp expects a number (UNIX timestamp), so my guess is that it's being given a string or NULL.

Comment: I am pretty much a newb to PHP and I'm trying to navigate through someone else's code. Is there a way to see what `get_post_meta` is returning?